# Two player infinite game - chance of it being a particular player's turn in the middle of the game?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

Two players take turns. Each turn:

> 1. There is a probability $p$ that the game ends. (Turn player wins, but that does not matter for this question)
> 2. Else it is the other player's turn.

At some point in the game, given that it hasn't ended, what is the probability $P$ that it is the first player's turn?

---

My attempts:

Intuitively, it feels like

$$\text{time it is first player's turn}:\text{time it is second player's turn}=1:p$$

Hence we get $$P=\frac{1}{p+1}$$

Alternatively (I'm not sure I can exactly explain this method),

$$P=(1-p)+p^2P$$
$\implies$
$$(1-p^2)P=1-p$$
$\implies$
$$P=\frac{1}{p+1}$$

This came from considering the state 'it is the first player's turn' in the game... but I can't quite see how this relates to the answer any more.

---

I'm not sure on my answer and would appreciate an explanation of the second method if it is correct (I feel that it somehow 'works', but can't quite put it into words). Alternative solutions appreciated too.

---

Clarification:

It is hard to explain what is meant by 'some point in the game' rigorously, so perhaps the following way of expressing $P$ will make this clear:

Let $P_k$ be the probability that the game ends on the $k$th turn.

Then

$$P = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil P_k$$

Comment: It seems to me that this only makes sense as a conditional probability, since in the long run, the absolute probability that it’s *anyone’s* turn approaches zero.

Comment: @amd Edited for clarity

Comment: I think that you have to define “at some point in the game” more precisely to be able to compute a definite probability. My guess is that the probability you’re looking for is simply equal to the probability that you’ve sampled the game on an odd-numbered turn.

Comment: @amd How about this - $P = \sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}\left\lceil\frac{k}{2}\right\rceil P_k$?

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively a markov chain with three states:

1: Player 1's turn,

2: Player 2's turn,

0: Game-end.

The game-end represents any given player winning. We then have $P(1\rightarrow 2)=P(2\rightarrow 1)=1-p$,  $P(1\rightarrow 0)=P(2\rightarrow 0)=p$ and $P(0\rightarrow 0)=1$.

Since players alternate, we only consider times $t=2k+1$ for player 1. Then the probability of player 1's turn at time $t=2k+1$ is $(1-p)^{t-1}.$ As an example if $t=3$, then we need the first two turns to result in a non-win, giving $(1-p)^2$.

Note that it doesn't really make sense to not specify $t$ here.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to get from here to the answer. The question is interested in the conditional probability of it being a certain player's turn at time $t$...

Comment: It's $(1-p)^{t-1}$, as written in the answer.

Comment: That's not what the question asks for - 'at some point in the game' meaning, 'given some random point in the game'